# electron-quick-start packaged with electron-packager, gives 116MB

Tags: electron, electron-packager

I just packaged the [electron-quick-start](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start) and then installed `electron-packager` and ran: `node_modules\.bin\electron-packager ./ --platform=win32 --arch=ia32,x64 --out=releases --asar`. My `main.js` is barely 1KB. The folders are of size 96MB and 116MB. That is way too huge for this app, which does pretty much nothing. Why is the size so huge? Am I doing something wrong? Is there any wat to reduce the size? Becuase electron is taking up more diskspace than my actual app, so if I ever distribute an electron app it would be insanely huge.

Why is this happening?

Comment: I really don't want to use electron if it alone is going to be larger than a fully fledged browser

Comment: Electron packager keeps the original source folder along with your pacckaged file, which is an .asar file. When you have generated the asar file, you don't need the source folder anymore and can delete that. It will cut down the size of your app.

Comment: @SandipGhosh I actually, inside the folders, only see `electron.asar` and `app.asar`. In the folder `resources`. There are a lot of DLLs though.

Comment: "I really don't want to use electron if it alone is going to be larger than a fully fledged browser" => then really do not use electron, because it **is** an almost fully fledged browser + a server.

Comment: @ghybs Are there any alternatives which allow desktop apps with JS? I find C++ to be more barebones and difficult.

Comment: Electron is the best platform, if you want to create desktop app with javascript and html. The thing to keep in mind is that you are using the layout engine, javascript engine of a browser alongwith a backend server. So, whatever other options you might choose, it will cost you huge by means of the size of the application. That being said, NW.js(https://nwjs.io/) is another option you can opt for, although it doesn't provide you any added advantage.

Comment: For Windows only, you can also make UWP apps in JavaScript.

Comment: You want fancy modern crossplatform HTML and JS support? You gonne need a full browser process. Whats your problem with ~120mb as a baseline? The js files you add won't surpass 15MB and the assets will probably get you to a total of 200MB. Even if you use QT webviews you'll end up with similar sizes.